# MongoDB Find object within array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to find if a Username exists within my account collection. One account can have multiple users, but I'm trying to check if the username exists before I create an object with that username and return it if it does.

For now, I'm focusing on simply checking if it does exist. This is what I currently have:

```
const acc = await Account.findOne({"Email": req.body.Email});
if(!acc) throw Error('Email not found');
if(Account.findOne({"Users.Username":req.body.User.Username})) throw Error('Username already exists');
```

Edit: Not sure if this will help, but it's throwing the error, even when the User array is empty

Comment: I couldn't understand what's the problem in this explanation , Could you make your question more clarify and where is `await` for the second query ?

Comment: @MohammadMomeni Yeah, that await was the issue. I was trying to check if there was an object with an identical property value. It wasn't best explained, I admit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
Account.findOne({"Users.Username":req.body.User.Username})
```

will return a promise, which, regardless of what it will ultimately resolve to, will evaluate to `true` here `if(Account.findOne({"Users.Username":req.body.User.Username}))`. So it's really no wonder your code throws that `Username already exists` error every time you run it.

You should change it to look what your first find looks like (i.e using `await`), or do something like this:

```
Account.findOne({"Users.Username":req.body.User.Username})
   .then(result => {
      if(result)
         throw Error('Username already exists');
      else
        ...
   })
   .catch(e => {...})
```

Comment: Yeah, that added await seemed to have been the issue. Thank you

Comment: How would I set the User that is found to a variable?

Comment: @FallingInForward The same way you do it with the first `await`: `const user = await Account.findOne({"Users.Username":req.body.User.Username})`. Or using the promise structure I showed in the answer.

Comment: That returns the entire account document. Users are an array of documents that is stored in each account

Comment: @FallingInForward If you show me a sample doc, I can show you how to retrieve the specific user from that array.

Comment: I've asked a new question where I've put everything I think you need. Here's a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66725757/mongodb-nodejs-return-subdocument